# Adding 2D array to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a DataFrame from these two lists

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [7,8,9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['First'])
df['Second'] = b
df
```

This is the output I got-

```
    First   Second
0       a   [1, 2, 3]
1       b   [4, 5]
2       c   [7, 8, 9]
```

How can I get rid of the [ ]  brackets to get my expected output?

My expected output is

```
    First   Second
0       a   1, 2, 3
1       b   4, 5
2       c   7, 8, 9
```

Comment: `[]` is a normal part of a `list` object. What makes you want to get rid of it? Do you really want a literal string like `1, 2, 3` for future use?

Comment: I don't recommend storing sequences as elements in a dataframe. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you `a` is really related to `[1,2,3]` you might like to have a look at [`pd.explode'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the column to a string type and strip the square brackets

```
df['Second'] =  df['Second'].astype(str).str.strip('[]')
```

Comment: I have edited it and thanks for the suggestion @Paul. I needed to first convert that to a string type

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here? A column with list of numeric values that is not a list? It seems bit counter-intuitive. You can maybe convert the values to string to get rid of the so called square brackets of list representation.

```
c = [", ".join(str(x) for x in y) for y in b]
df['Second'] = c
```

This will get rid of the brackets. But I am not really sure what is the use of it or what is your actual use-case.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to first process the list of lists to convert it to the required type.

The question about usefulness of storing comma-separated numbers in a dataframe still remains as you won't be able to perform any computation on that.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [7,8,9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['First'])

df['Second'] = [','.join(map(str, i)) for i in b]

    First   Second
0   a       1,2,3
1   b       4,5
2   c       7,8,9
```